# React isn't generating account number state first time because it is null

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

The account number is part of `userData` and I'm displaing `userData` in another component. It is genrating the account number perfectly but not the first time because it is set to `null`.

I tried to use `useEffect` but then it is just generating the same number for every create

```js
function CreateAccount() {
  // Define state variables to manage user input``
  const [fullName, setFullName] = useState("");
  const [balance, setBalance] = useState(null);
  const [gender, setGender] = useState("");
  const [address, setAddress] = useState("");
  const [accountNumber, setAccountNumber] = useState(null);

  // Get the setUserData function from the RegisterContext
  const { setUserData } = useContext(RegisterContext);

  // Function to handle form submission
  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    // Generate account number
    const generatedAccountNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000000000);

    // Gather user input data including the generated account number
    const userData = {
      fullName,
      balance,
      gender,
      address,
      accountNumber
    };

    // Update the userData state in the context provider
    setUserData(userData);

    // Set the accountNumber state once
    setAccountNumber(generatedAccountNumber);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem will be resolved if you call your `Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000000000)` in the `useState` hook `const [accountNumber, setAccountNumber] = useState(null);`

This will init the state with a random "account number" every time.

I modified your code a bit to init the `accountNumber` state on mount

```js
// suggestion to move this function yo maybe utils.js or something 
function generateAccountId() {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000000000);
  };
 

function CreateAccount() {
  // Define state variables to manage user input``
  const [fullName, setFullName] = useState("");
  const [balance, setBalance] = useState(null);
  const [gender, setGender] = useState("");
  const [address, setAddress] = useState("");
  // When the component is mounted we generate an account ID
  const [accountNumber, setAccountNumber] = useState(generateAccountId);

  // Get the setUserData function from the RegisterContext
  const { setUserData } = useContext(RegisterContext);

  // Function to handle form submission
  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    // Gather user input data including the generated account number
    const userData = {
      fullName,
      balance,
      gender,
      address,
      accountNumber
    };

    // Update the userData state in the context provider
    setUserData(userData);
}
```

After this modification, every time your component mounts the `accountNumber` will be generated for you in the `useState` hook. You can init `useState` with a function which is the approach I used.

### No state solution

Another improvement would be not to even use state at all, just do this

```js
   // Gather user input data and generate an account id
    const userData = {
      fullName,
      balance,
      gender,
      address,
      accountNumber:generateAccountId()
    };
```

This will always generate a new accountNumber when the `userDetails` object is created